# using esc_html_e string in custom form using code snippets

Tags: forms

I needed to create a custom form to implement a custom payment method (it is a donations form).
I decided to use Code Snippets plugin and create the form in there. Every step is a snippet and every snippet is a page.
So i got a form like(too long to paste all):

```
add_shortcode( 'don_form', function () {

$out = '<form class="uk-form uk-form-stacked" action="https://www.example.com/donation-page/" method="POST">
<legend>Title</legend>

    <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-1-3">
        
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-margin-top"><label class="uk-form-label" for="firstname"><span class="uk-text-danger">* </span>'. esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ).':</label><input class="uk-form-large uk-width-1-1" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required></div> 
/*.............rest of the form........*/
<div class="uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-top"><input class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large" type="submit" value="Next"></div>
        
    </div>
</form>';

return $out;} );
```

It works ok but.....

esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ) shows at the top of the page in the front end instead of inside the label tag.
Why? is such usage not correct?

Comment: The way you've used  `esc_html_e` isn't  right, the `_e` part outputs, but you're trying to append it. Shortcodes shouldn't output their content, and what you've done is equivalent to: `echo "hello" . echo $stuff . " world";` which doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how should i call such strings inside a function used via shortcode? Is the whole choise of using code snippets for such purpose, wrong?

Comment: it's a basic PHP issue, a  shortcode is a function that returns a string, that string is the content of the shortcode. But your code has a function call that directly outputs, `esc_html_e`, it does not return it. You cannot use `esc_html_e` like that, it is innapropriate. This is a grave mistake. Note that any answer  you get here will require at least basic programming knowledge